# .Net Core 2.2 App Returning 404 for every call on Linux AWS Instance

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel-http-server, .net-core-2.2

I setup a .Net Core application on an AWS EC2 instance and can't seem to get my calls to succeed.
Specifically, I find that routes that work just fine on my localhost when I run locally do not work on this Linux box. I followed some instructions from Microsoft to setup Kestrel with an nginx reverse proxy.

Relevent details:

I have a working route that functions on my localhost:

```
[HttpGet("test")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Test()
{
    return Ok("WORKED");
}
```

On my Linux box, I start dotnet (and have verified nginx is running). I do dotnet MyApp.dll and it says it's listening.

I now make a Postman call to http://api.mydomainhere.com

and in my command/terminal where I have dotnet running, I see the request come in:

```
[ec2-user@xxxxxx MyApp]$ dotnet MyApp.dll
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using '/home/ec2-user/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /home/ec2-user/MyApp
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://api.mydomainhere.com/api/users/Test application/json 119
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 67.8504ms 404 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[32]
      Connection id "0HM0NUJ8Q68OU", Request id "0HM0NUJ8Q68OU:00000001": the application completed without reading the entire request body.
```

My nginx setup is:

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   _;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Despite this, when I call /api/users/test, it 404's me, and if I run the same test locally, it works. Is there a misconfiguration in my app settings in .Net or anything like that?

If I try a curl command from the Linux instance I also get a 404, which means I can't even hit the .Net app right?

ec2-user@xxxx ~]$ **curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:5000/api/users/test**

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET /api/users/test HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Wed, 24 Jun 2020 04:22:41 GMT
< Server: Kestrel
< Content-Length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Any suggestions or areas to start looking at?

Thank you!

Comment: I am also getting same issue. I followed this document(https://aamersadiq.github.io/2019/Deploying-DotNet-Core-On-Aws-Linux/) and have deployed .net core 2.2 application which is showing up and running in the console but when trying to access the url it keeps giving me 404

Answer (score 0):

For those who as despaired as was me, I composed small checklist, which worked for me (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72935044/4745982) question):

1. Comment `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` line in your nginx host configuraion in

`sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/<your-site>`

or/and

`sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

as it's testing if a certain url exists on the file system and if not return 404.

2. Also I commented all content in `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file to be sure that nothing excess prevents the api from working (**ONLY** if your api configuration is in separate file like `/etc/nginx/sites-available/<your-site>`)

Then restart nginx:
`sudo systemctl restart nginx && systemctl status nginx`

3. In your dotnet project, check that redirect middleware is only used in production environment or try to comment for all environments to detect if this is the problem (worked for my case)

```
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection(); //leave like this or try to comment it just for checking
}
```

4. Also in your dotnet project, check if you have your api path setting. Something like:

```
app.UsePathBase(apiBasePath);
```

Make sure, that this path is the same as `location` setting in files from step one.
Of course, don't forget to **upload your project on server** if changes happened and restart your api service:

`sudo systemctl restart your-kestrel-api.service`

Comment: .NET Core 2.x went out of support a long time ago. The Long-Term-Support versions are .NET Core 3.1 which reaches End-Of-Life in December 2022 and .NET (Core) 6 which is supported until November 2024

Comment: This list is working for .net 6 I am using now, as much as for previous versions, I believe. Anyway, there are so many posts with this kind of problem leaved unanswered here, so I believe it will help a lot of people

Comment: MS docs describe [how to deploy to Linux with NGINX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-6.0) while AWS has a section that [shows how to do the same with Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-linux-getting-started.html). I suspect the reason the questions remain unanswered is because they're unclear and/or the original poster soon finds the tutorials and the AWS toolbox. .NET Core on AWS is no longer new.

Comment: Or perhaps people decide they don't want to install and maintain NGINX themselves and use Beanstalk after all. Especially when the AWS tutorials point them to that direction

Comment: Maybe so, maybe not. We're both don't know.  As for me, I had serious investigation and really hard times around this problem and composed the answer from own experience of try-and-check. If this list doesn't have its value - it will sink under a negative rating. So, let community show