# HTTP get Status code 404 when trying to a .Net project in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, ubuntu

i am trying to Run a .Net project in Linux machine, the build shows Successfull without any error.

Following is the General Header Information for the Browser.

```
Request URL: https://localhost:5001/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 
Remote Address: [::1]:5001
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

where as on the other hand on windows the Browser seems to run correct with 200 reason code. please advice.

Comment: What kind if project? ASP.NET Core WebAPI? Did you try to run it on Windows using Kestrel?

Comment: Yes It is ASP.NET Core WebAPI, yeah it is working fine on Kestrel from Windows.

Comment: The issue might be relates the reverse proxy server setting (for example the port) and the firewall (make sure the port is useful), you can refer the following tutorial to check the reverse proxy server setting:[Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Nginx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and [How To Deploy .Net Core Application On Linux
](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-deploy-net-core-application-on-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

A little checklist, which worked for me:

1. Comment `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` line in your nginx host configuraion in

`sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/<your-site>`

or/and

`sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

as it's testing if a certain url exists on the file system and if not return 404.

2. Also I commented all content in `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file to be sure that nothing excess prevents the api from working (if your api configuration is in separate file like `/etc/nginx/sites-available/<your-site>`)

Restart nginx then
`sudo systemctl restart nginx && systemctl status nginx`

3. In your dotnet project, check that redirect middleware is only used in production environment or try to comment for all environments to detect if this is the problem (worked for my case)

```
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection(); //leave like this or try to comment it just for checking
}
```

4. Also in your dotnet project, check if you have your api path setting. Something like:

```
app.UsePathBase(apiBasePath);
```

Make sure, that this path is the same as `location` setting in files from step one.
Of course, don't forget to **upload your project on server** if changes happened and restart your api service:

`sudo systemctl restart your-kestrel-api.service`

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was removing middleware for https

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```